# Probability of getting heads again.

Tags: probability

We flip a coin and get heads, now we flip it again, and again we get heads. What is the probability that the third time we flip it, we get heads? Math says that when we flip it again it will have a 50% probability of getting heads again as the coin is not affected by the previous outcomes, but that seems wrong. Shouldn't the probability of getting a tails be higher now?

Comment: Is the coin known to be fair?

Comment: @79037662 , yes.

Comment: Then of course there is a 50% chance of getting heads, that's what "fair coin" means. What seems wrong about it?

Comment: See Gambler's fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: On the other hand, if the coin is believed to be biased but how it is biased is unknown, then seeing two heads might suggests that the third flip may be more likely to be heads than tails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the math seems wrong, it is correct. Maybe the following argument can help your intuition:

There are eight possible outcomes for three coin flips ($H$ stands for heads, $T$ for tails): $HHH, HHT, HTH, HTT, THH, THT, TTH, TTT$. All of these outcomes will be equally likely.

After two heads are flipped, there are only two possible outcomes remaining: $HHT$ and $HHH$. The final coin flip is a fair choice between these two outcomes.

---

Your skepticism of this result is called the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy), and it might be due to what happens in the following similar-sounding situation:

Suppose you ask your friend to secretly flip three coins and count the heads. You ask him "Are at least two heads shown?" Your friend answers yes. So now what is the probability (from your perspective) that all three coins show heads?

The answer is actually $25\%$! That's because your friend's answer only reduces the possible outcomes to four: $HHH, HHT, HTH, THH$. They are still equally likely. Of these four outcomes, only one outcome contains three heads.

---

Now here's yet another variation of the situation that highlights that probability is really tricky. Suppose your friend flips three coins and puts them into one opaque box each before giving them to you. Now you choose two boxes at random and open them. The coins in both boxes show heads. What is the probability that the coin in the third box also shows heads?

You might think that there are four outcomes remaining: $HHH, HHT, HTH, THH$, as in the previous situation, and that the probability is thus $25\%$. Unfortunately, you're wrong, and the true probability (from your perspective) is 50%. Why's that? Because since you added your own randomness to the mix, we have more than eight possible outcomes. Let a digit denote the box you haven't opened yet (e.g. $HHT3$ denotes that you opened boxes 1 and 2, which contained heads, but the third box contains tails). There are 24 possible situations:

$HHH1, HHT1, HTH1, HTT1, THH1, THT1, TTH1, TTT1$,

$HHH2, HHT2, HTH2, HTT2, THH2, THT2, TTH2, TTT2$,

$HHH3, HHT3, HTH3, HTT3, THH3, THT3, TTH3, TTT3$.

After choosing two boxes to open and seeing heads in both, only two scenarios remain (depending on the box you picked): $HHH1$ and $THH1$, or $HHH2$ and $HTH2$, or $HHH3$ and $HHT3$. The two remaining scenarios are always equally likely, so the probability that the last box contains a head is 50% again.